# Instantiate custom Page written in code within XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, constructor, xamarin.forms

First of all, a small warning - we are talking `Xamarin` here and, unfortunately, not `WPF`. I am converting existing code based pages into `XAML` representation with cross-platform `Xamarin Forms`. I have a class of the following form:

```
public class ExtendedNavigationPage : BaseNavigationPage
{      
    public ExtendedNavigationPage(Xamarin.Forms.Page root)
        :base(root)
    {
    }
}
```

So now I need to use it within `XAML`. My initial thought was that I could pass `Page` parameter of the constructor as this:

```
<page:ExtendedNavigationPage>
  <view:MyContentView/>
</page:ExtendedNavigationPage>
```

Where `MyContentView` is a `Page`.

However, I cannot wrap it like that, Visual Studio tells me that there is no parameterless constructor. Now I am wondering if it is even possible to instantiate  a custom page like mine within `XAML`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, NavigationPage doesn't have a "View" property. It's common practice to include a Page in its constructor, which I'm guessing may contribute to your error about the parameterless constructor not existing.

I also have to mention that in most cases instantiating NavigationPages in XAML is unnecessary. Now that I got that out of the way, here's how you can do it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<NavigationPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="My.Shared.Page">
    <x:Arguments>
        <Page>
            <ScrollView>
                <StackLayout x:Name="layout" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Center">  
                <ActivityIndicator x:Name="activity"></ActivityIndicator>                                                   
                </StackLayout>  
            </ScrollView>    
        </Page>    
    </x:Arguments>
</NavigationPage>
```

The important line here is the fourth line:

```
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
```

xaml 2009 supports this behavior.

For a more complete discussion on this topic see [this forum post](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17704/navigationpage-in-xaml).
Credit to [@Stephane Delcroix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1063783/stephane-delcroix) on this.